# How do I add Jquery after loading magento 1.8's default js or css?

Tags: magento-1.8, css, prototype-js

How do I add Jquery after loading magento default js or css? I want to add js product listing page before protype.js loads can you tell me what i need to do for this?
Here is my Local.xml file

```
<default>
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery_min.js</script></action>
 <action method="addJs"><type>external_js</type><script>jquery/jquery_migrate.js</script></action>    
  </reference>
  </default>
```

I found this error in protype.js. i want to add jquery before this. What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Use `addJs` instead of `addExternalItem`.
or if you want them below all the other css and js files use this:

```
<reference name="head">
   <block type="core/template" template="custom/js.phtml" name="jquery" />
</reference>
```

Then create `custom/js.phtml` inside your theme with this content:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'/jquery/jquery_min.js'?>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'/jquery/jquery_migrate.js'?>">
```

Comment: I want to add js product listing page brfore protype.js can you tell me what i do for it?

Answer (score 0):

Insert after load prototype.js and need to create on directory in magento/js/dirneme

try this way

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">

<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
<!-- After prototype js load jquery -->

<action method="addJs"><script>dirneme/jquery.1.10.js</script></action>
</block>
```